# Application-scope variables in Flask

Tags: python, flask

In Flask, within create_app, I'm declaring a few blank lists.

```
def create_app(settings_key='dev'):
    veggies = []
    fruit = []
```

I tried updating those lists like this:

```
def create_app(settings_key='dev'):
    veggies = []
    fruit = []

    @app.route('/update')
    def update():
        veggies.append('potato')
        fruit.append('plum')
```

And then, after accessing /update, I would like to go to a different @app.route and use those lists.

However, When I do it the way I described above, those lists don't get updated. I'm assuming this is due to the variables not being application-scope. How can I get around this?

Edit: example of code used in a different @app.route

```
    @app.route('/market')
    def market():
        all_for_same = []
        for veg in veggies:
            all_for_sale.append(veg)
        for fr in fruit:
            all_for_sale.append(fr)
```

The /update is of course a little more complex and involves reading from a file that gets updated/a SQL query.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use those lists in a different @app.route?

Comment: If these are per session why not store them there? Also if you ever deploy that code there is no way to guarantee that these will be persistent.

Comment: My goal is to have the /update route only be used internally to update the code with some information from the database. Other routes will be used by some PHP code in order to process some information. So, ideally, the service will start up and run indefinitely and I will be able to refresh the data once a day or so without restarting the service. That data will be able to used by whoever is in the PHP session.